# How to get no of days from MON-YYYY data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please let me know how can i get number of days in a month when I give date in `MMM-YYYY` format.

Eg: `JAN-2017` = `31`

Any helps appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using? Date functions are not universal between databases.

Comment: you need to specify which version of `SQL` you are using.As people need to keep in mind the version scenario while posting the answer

Comment: Are you using SQLServer, mySQL, ...?

Comment: I am sorry, I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check This.

```
    declare @D varchar(20)
    set @D ='JAN-2017'
    select  
    datediff(day, '01-'+@D, dateadd(month, 1,'01-'+ @D)) as NoOfDay
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..........`enter code here`

SELECT day(GETDATE() )

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server you can do that with the first day of the specified month

```
select datediff(day, @date, dateadd(month, 1, @date))
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL users...

```
SET @convertedDate = STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( '01-',
                                          'Jan-2017' ),
                                  '%d-%b-%y' );
SELECT DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD( @convertedDate,
                           INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
                 @convertedDate ) AS NumOfDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'Feb-2017' bit is your column or variable

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY, EOMONTH('01-' + 'Feb-2017'))
```